# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I get a JSON from my response object so I do:

`var json = JSON.parse(res.text);`

I print the JSON and get JSON back. But when I retrieve the value inside `json.body.value.total` then it gives this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined
```

I have no idea why. I pasted the value that receive from var json and printed on console and was able to retrieve total. But I cannot do it through the code. There is a JSON value total. Its just unable to recognize. On the console, it works but does not work in the code.

I get JSON back from my response object which I retrieve using `response.text`. I think it needs to change in parsable object but all it returns is `undefined`

```
it('returns http 200', function (done) {
        chai
        .request(baseUrl)
        .get('/api/')
        .set('Authorization', 'Basic abc')
        .query({val:'hey'})
        .end(function(err, res) {
            expect(res).to.have.status(200);

            var json = res.text;

            console.log('val: '+ JSON.parse(json.body));
            var val = json.body.value.total; //undefined
            expect(val.to.be.above(0)); //fails
            done();
        });
    });
```

Comment: please provide your full code.

Comment: The error means that `json.value` is `undefined`, which in turn means that `json` (most likely) doesn't have such a property.

Comment: @FelixKling it has a property called json.value as when I do the same thing in console, it works.

Comment: Obviously `json` is not what you think it is then. However, we can't help you without a *complete* example. Please read [mcve].

Comment: @FelixKling I pasted code

Comment: In your code you are doing `var json = res.text;` instead of `var json = JSON.parse(res.text);` or `var json = JSON.parse(res.text.body);` (not sure which part contains the JSON). I guess `json.body` is a string.

Comment: What does that console log line show?

Comment: @FelixKling I tried that but it did not work. I posted the answer that did. Although it helped me direct my thoughts. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `REST API` that I built was returning the `response.body` but what worked is this:

```
var body = JSON.parse(json.body);
var obj = JSON.stringify(body);
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(obj);
```

The above looks ridiculous but thats what worked. `json -> object -> json`. It was finding trouble to figure out that its a json object.

The console was doing a good job but not the library that I was using.

The complete code is this:

```
it('returns http 200', function (done) {
        chai
        .request(baseUrl)
        .get('/api/')
        .set('Authorization', 'Basic abc')
        .query({val:'hey'})
        .end(function(err, res) {
            expect(res).to.have.status(200);

            var json = res.text;

            var body = JSON.parse(json.body);
            var obj = JSON.stringify(body);
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(obj);
            var val = jsonObj.body.value.total;
            expect(val.to.be.above(0));
            done();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put you json string into `JSON.Parse()` and access the properties on the result of the Parse function.

You can't just access properties from a text.

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning the parsed value to `json`.

```
var json = res.text;
```

should be

```
var json = JSON.parse(res.text);
```